# Unable to extract an array from the response of the server retrofit android, as a result I have a crash?

Tags: android, retrofit

I'm working in the application with incoming and outgoing messages. There are some messages with attached files, and at the moment I'm working on something that would somehow get these attachments, that is, download to the phone. In order to download the file, I need to know two things: its name and the id of the message in which it is present. To display the entire message, I have the ViewMessage class:

```
public class ViewMessage {
    @SerializedName("date")
    @Expose
    private String date;
    @SerializedName("type")
    @Expose
    private String type;
    @SerializedName("user_id")
    @Expose
    private String userId;
    @SerializedName("body")
    @Expose
    private String body;
    @SerializedName("can_delete")
    @Expose
    private String canDelete;
    @SerializedName("can_reply")
    @Expose
    private String canReply;
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("subject")
    @Expose
    private String subject;


    @SerializedName("attach")
    private FileData[] attach;

    private boolean hasAttaches() {
        return attach != null && attach.length > 0;
    }

    public String[] getAttachesNames() {
        if(hasAttaches())
        {
            String[] names = new String[attach.length];
            line 44 at my error logs - System.arraycopy(attach, 0, names, 0, attach.length);
            return names;
        }
        return new String[0];
    }


    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    public void setBody(String body) {
        this.body = body;
    }

    public String getCanDelete() {
        return canDelete;
    }

    public void setCanDelete(String canDelete) {
        this.canDelete = canDelete;
    }

    public String getCanReply() {
        return canReply;
    }

    public void setCanReply(String canReply) {
        this.canReply = canReply;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSubject() {
        return subject;
    }


    public void setSubject(String subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
    }


}


class FileData{
    private String name;
    private float size;
}
```

Then I try to cause to cause function of extraction of an array in the main class:

```
String file_name[] = Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).getAttachesNames();
                    line 144 in my error: for (String aFile_name : file_name) {
                        txt.append(Arrays.toString(file_name) + "/n");
                    }
```

but as a result, my application breaks down, with an error:

```
08-21 09:41:58.342 E: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.developer_4.test_login, PID: 3462
    java.lang.ArrayStoreException: source[0] of type com.example.developer_4.test_login.data.model.FileData cannot be stored in destination array of type java.lang.String[]
        at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
        at com.example.developer_4.test_login.data.model.ViewMessage.getAttachesNames(ViewMessage.java:44)
        at com.example.developer_4.test_login.ActionsMessages.MessageShow$2.onResponse(MessageShow.java:144)
        at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:70)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are trying to typecast FileData[] to String[]. Please use some other way or just post your response and FileData class, so that, I can help you.

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, or fortunately, I solved my problem, but now there was a problem with outputting an array of file attachments, most likely I will create a new question, or I can update the current question with new data.

Answer (score 1):

Try to changing your for loop as like this

```
String file_name[] = Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).getAttachesNames();

                    for (int i = 0, i<aFile_name.size(); i++) {
                        txt.append(String.valueOf(aFile_name.get(i)) + "/n");
                     }
```